# Defining a constructor of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am currently going through Bjarne Stroustrup's **"The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)"** and am trying to understand whether is the following *a syntax error* or *was it the way I compiled it*.

According to the following code snippet (extracted from the book), my constructor should look like this:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s): elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}   // Construct a Vector
    ...
private:
    double* elem; // Pointer to the elements
    int sz;       // The number of elements
};
```

But, I am unable to compile it unless I change the following as per the suggestion of the error message:

```
Vector(int s): elem(new double[s]), sz(s) {}
```

Note: I compiled my C++ codes using the following command through the Mac Terminal:

```
g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall Test.cpp -o Test.o
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60e9110e109953e2). What's your compiler version?

Comment: why you initialize elem in class member initialization?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Why not?

Comment: My compiler version is 4.2.1.

Comment: `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c++98`. The fourth edition is a C++11 book.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is a good idea to initialize elem from size while size is being initialized?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @Maxwell With `4.2.1` c++11 isn't enabled by default. Also as molbdnilo pointed out `-ansi` forces to use c++98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, all you need to do is to compile it for C++ 11:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -ansi -pedantic -Wall Test.cpp -o Test.o
```

---

As @molbdnilo pointed out in a comment, remove `-ansi` from the command, because this is a synonym for `std=c89` or `std=c++98`.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall Test.cpp -o Test.o
```

Comment: I tried this command but I do still get the same error message whereby it is expecting a '(' instead of '{'.

Comment: You don't want `-ansi` in there.

Comment: Thank you, @molbdnilo!

That does the trick!

P/S:
How do I up vote your comment?  I tried hovering over to the comment but nothing pops up...

Comment: Another correction: when compiling C++, `-ansi` is a synonym for `-std=c++98` (not `c89`). When you indicate several standards, the last one is the one that counts. `-ansi -std=c++11` would work, but be pointless.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @molbdnilo!  I tried it and it works, but as you mention, it is rather pointless to do so.P/S: I am so sorry as I am still unable to up vote your comment.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo, I didn't know that `-ansi` option at all.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @alain, I think the reason I am unable to see the 'up-arrow' when I hover over the comment might be due to my low reputation.  According to my profile, I need 15 reputation in order to unlock flags and voting.